# Count the occurrences of a foreign key that references a primary key in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Let's say I have table `patients` that looks like this:

```
+------------+------------+-----------+----------------+
| id_patient | first_name | last_name | recommended_by |
+------------+------------+-----------+----------------+
|          1 | Joe        | Bronson   |           NULL |
|          2 | Jack       | Jackson   |              1 |
|          3 | Jon        | Jonson    |              1 |
+------------+------------+-----------+----------------+
```

The column `recommended_by` is a foreign key that represents another row in the patient table. I want to count the number of recommendations each patient has given. I used this query:

```
SELECT recommended_by, count(recommended_by)
FROM patients
GROUP BY recommended_by;
```

Which gives this result:

```
+----------------+-----------------------+
| recommended_by | count(recommended_by) |
+----------------+-----------------------+
|           NULL |                     0 |
|              1 |                     2 |
+----------------+-----------------------+
```

So it returns a patient_id and count of its recommendations. However, I want to include the first and last name for that patient. How can I create the query to return a list of all patients who made recommendations and how many they made?

For example, the above result would return:

```
| id_patient | first_name | last_name | recommendations |
+------------+------------+-----------+-----------------+
|          1 | Joe        | Bronson   |               2 |
```

Comment: comma seperate them for each recommendation?

Comment: Could this question be clearer, I wonder?

Comment: Ok, which part you don't understand?

Comment: _“How could I use that recommended_by value to extract first_name and last_name from my patients table?”_ – with a sub-query or a JOIN.

Comment: If I was asking a question like this, I would provide an example of the desired result, given the dataset provided.

Comment: Basically result would be: `1 | Joe | Bronson | 2`

Comment: `2` is number of recommendation that `Joe Bronson` made.

Comment: So, you want a list of all users who made a recommendations, and a count of all the recommendations they made?

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your question accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were off to a good start. If I were approaching this problem, I would first write a subquery to get the number of times each `id` appears in the `recommended_by` column. You've done that:

```
SELECT recommended_by, COUNT(*) AS numRecommendations
FROM patients
GROUP BY recommended_by;
```

What you can do then, is join this subquery with your original query on the condition that `id = recommended_by`. I would suggest a `LEFT JOIN`. If a patient has never recommended someone, you will get a null value. Use COALESCE to change it to 0:

```
SELECT p.*, COALESCE(t.numRecommendations, 0)
FROM patients p
LEFT JOIN(
   SELECT recommended_by, COUNT(*) AS numRecommendations
   FROM patients
   GROUP BY recommended_by) t ON t.recommended_by = p.id;
```

**EDIT**

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8af3f/4) demonstration.

Comment: No problem. If you don't want to see patients who have *never* made a recommendation, just remove coalesce and make it an inner join, and you'll only see people who have made recommendations. @BranislavLazic

Comment: I cannot see what the subquery does for us here.

Comment: @Strawberry the subquery gets the count of recommendations that each patient_id made. Then, it's joined back with the original table to get the other values. I have added an SQL Fiddle if that helps demonstrate the solution.

Comment: But you don't need it to be a subquery - and it will (I think) work better without it... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8af3f/11

Comment: @Strawberry you're right. Tested in MySQL workbench with 1000 random rows and it preformed in about half the time. Neither query was slow, though. I would post your own answer. If not, I will at least edit mine to share the alternative.

Comment: Hardly seems worth providing a separate answer. Just update yours.